# Passing data from an activity to a fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been looking at various examples on how to pass data and they all had a similar structure

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("params", "My String data");
MyFragment frag= new MyFragment();
frag.setArguments(bundle);
```

But it says my fragment does not contain a definition for setArguments

What am i doing wrong here?
And is there another method to pass data?

Edit:

When i run through this bit of code it says the bundle is null

```
Bundle bundle = this.Arguments;
        if (bundle != null)
        {

            string FirstName = bundle.GetString("FirstName");
            Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Yay it Worked", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Xamarin/C# normalization of the Android Fragment API, `setArguments` and `getArguments` becomes a C# property (`Arguments`):

```
frag.Arguments = bundle;
```

Comment: Thank you that solved it, and do you know by any chance how to retrieve it in my activity?

Comment: @Mortality `retrieve it in my activity`? do you mean your fragment?

Comment: Sorry, Yeah i meant Fragment

Comment: @Mortality just reverse it, within the fragment, `var bundle = this.Arguments;` and now that you have the Bundle, extract the data you placed in it. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use newInstance() design:

```
    public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
        public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
            BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString("param1", param1);
            args.putString("param2", param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
    }
```

and then in your activity:

```
   YourFragment frag = YouFragment.newInstance("a", "b");
```

Hope you get the idear.